# How can I change the datetime format in PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I use PHPspreadsheet to covert a xlsx file to a csv file.

In column "I" I have dates and times like `[26-04-2019  07:57:35]` how can I change this to `[2019-04-26 07:57:35]`?

I want to change this for uploading to MYSQL.

```
use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;

$xls_file = "$file";

$reader = new Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($xls_file);


$loadedSheetNames = $spreadsheet->getSheetNames();

$writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);

foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $writer->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $writer->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through each row of each sheet and change column `I` to the format needed for MySQL.

```
foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $writer->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $worksheet   = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRow  = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10

    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
        $datenow = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9,$row)->getValue();
        $worksheet->setCellValue('I' . $row,date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($datenow)));

    }  // end of for loop through the sheet

    $writer->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
}
```